# Getting Users to login to spotify using the API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, spotify-app

I'm trying to create an application that allows users to create preferred playlists on spotify. I am using the spotify web api and building an asp.net mvc application (c#). I am trying to make the web request to have users login to their spotify account, but for some reason my app does not redirect to the login page whenever I try to get the response.

I have tried creating a redirect link myself, but shouldn't the GetResponse() method invoke the redirect itself? I am new at this so I may be wrong but any help would be appreciated.

```
public IActionResult GetLogin()
    {
        string spotifyURL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/";
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(spotifyURL);

        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.Headers["client_id"] = clientID;
        webRequest.Headers["response_type"] = "code";
        webRequest.Headers["redirect_uri"] = "https://localhost:44383/home/login";

        string json = "";
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    //should get back a string i can then turn to json and parse for accesstoken
                    json = rdr.ReadToEnd();
                    rdr.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        bool authorized = true;
        if (authorized)
        {
            return View("Callback");// token.access_token;
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Home");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are trying to `authentificate` on spotify.

I can tell you you have a few mistakes you are using a `GET` method tho `authentificate`
   - The service waits a `POST` from you in `JSON` with account data like login and password, if the login and password and format will be correct it return you a `JSON` with access token.

**How to add a Header format:** `Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType = "application/json");`
After this the server will understand what content you actually sending to it.

A little about the last parts of code:

```
bool authorized = true;
        if (authorized)
        {
            return View("Callback");// token.access_token;
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Home");
        }
```

You returning like a blank `Views` here it is better to use

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "CpntrollerName", new { "Here you can pass any value" });
```

This will allow you to redirect to another `Controller` and `View` and pass a value to it.

Summary is:
I could write a long time but better to tell the real problem you should read more on how to use API in C# applications.

**Here I will provide you some links on MS documentations:**

The `WebRequest` method: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=netframework-4.8)

The `HttpClient` method: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8)

About HttpClient I recommend to use it only on desktop or mobile apps because it inherits from `.NET Framework` and not from `.NET Core` so it may cause an errors, but I didn't do a test on my ASP.NET Core applications so can't say for sure.

**Little tips:**

Use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) it will help you to serialize your JSON request and deserialize answer it is much easier then do it with your hands or Regex.

Use `async` and `Task` when making requests to the web, because answer can be long waited, and you don't want your app stay frozen until it waits an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help! But I'm failing to understand why I would need to use the POST method to call the authentication endpoint? According to the published spotify authorization code flow (https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/), the authenticate endpoint is a GET call and as I understand it, I do not need to get the user's login and password, the spotify service should ask for that right?

Comment: @fullstackmamba I see, it uses the inside registered application and gives you a token depending on it.
Then you should use `Bearer` header it contains access token in most cases.
I suggested you POST because in most cases if you build your own API or use another it needs some data from you like login and password, it was just part of explanation how API works in most cases.

In your case you nedd to do set header of your `GetRequest` like this: `myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);`